# When building and styling forms, is it better to use <table> tag or <div> tags?

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table, alignment

For example, I wish to make a form look like this (or similar):

[image]

In this case, is this a job better suited for  `<table>` tag, or is it a better practice to use `<div>` and CSS?

I am aware of the topic that CSS is to be used for styling and tables are for tabular data.  However, form is not quite tabular, so it will make sense to use CSS to style the form (to align the form elements).  But then table tag has clearly assigned tags (td, tr, tbody, thead, etc), and if I use divs insteady, they will somewhat blend in with other divs semantically.  i.e.  is used for container, then  is used for a form, they all become homogeneous and require further inspection to see which is which while table is clearly outlined

I wanted to inquire as to what is currently acceptable practice for building and styling forms.

Note:  Perhaps forms do not have to be aligned as below, but I am not aware of any other reasonable way to present a form.  Also, imagine you have 5 or 6 such forms next to each other, it is not just one.

Comment: I find it easier to style divs, but it's all a matter of preference - forms are classed as tabular as you have a heading followed by a field

Comment: The general consensus is that if it's not tabular data, don't use a table. You can, however, [use a div with `display: table`](https://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)

Comment: @Pete — That isn't tabular data. A series of key/value pairs is not tabular.

Comment: Use CSS. Use the most semantically appropriate element. labels and fieldsets may eliminate the need for divs.

Comment: @Quentin the definition of tabular: *of, relating to, or arranged in a table or systematic arrangement by columns, rows, etc., as statistics. ascertained from or computed by the use of tables. having the form of a table, tablet, or tablature.* I see the above form as a systematic arrangement of columns - your left column is a header, the right column is the value - I never said anything about data

Comment: Also from w3c - lets got to the source of standards: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html - *The HTML table model allows authors to arrange data -- text, preformatted text, images, links, forms, form fields, other tables, etc. -- into rows and columns of cells.*

Answer (score 1):

You should use divs. Frameworks like Bootstrap have excellent systems for laying these out in ways that are very mobile responsive and so much better than tables.

If you're in any doubt, check out this link... http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com